# Working with Typescript Interfaces- error: property does not exist

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-toolkit

I built this interface

```
export interface UserInfo {
    success?: boolean,
    user?: User,
    employer?: Employer,
    hr?: Hr
}
```

Now when I do this

```
let data = await loginUser(loginData);
console.log(data.success);
```

loginUser method code:

```
import {createApi, fetchBaseQuery} from "@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react";
import {BASE_API_ENDPOINT, LOGIN_API_ENDPOINT} from "../../constants/apis";
import {LoginData, UserInfo} from "../../models/apis/UserData";

export const loginApi = createApi({
    reducerPath: 'loginReducer',
    baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: BASE_API_ENDPOINT }),
    endpoints: (builder) => ({
        loginUser: builder.mutation<UserInfo, LoginData> ({
            query: (data: LoginData) => ({
                    url: LOGIN_API_ENDPOINT,
                    method: "POST",
                    body: data
            }),
            transformResponse: (rawResult : UserInfo) => {
                return rawResult
            }
        })
    })
})
export const { useLoginUserMutation } = loginApi;
```

I get this error

> Property 'success' does not exist on type '{ data: UserInfo; } | { error: FetchBaseQueryError | SerializedError; }'.

I am a newbie with typescript, and I want to access UserInfo object from { data: UserInfo; } but I am not being able to do so. Can anyone help?

Comment: This looks like a bad method typing. Can you also show us the code of `loginUser()`?

Comment: Does `loginUser` api returns `{ data: UserInfo; }` as response?

Comment: I have added the loginUser method in the description

Comment: The error indicates that the data you are working with *may not be a success result*. In this case, you would need to narrow the type with a type guard.

Comment: Console.log your response or check it on postman what response you get

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens because the property "success" exists only on type UserInfo.
Since it's a union type the compiler can't be sure whether the function returns a data object (with UserInfo type) or an error object (FetchBaseQueryError | SerializedError)

In order to access the success property of the response, you can firstly check if it exists

```
if("success" in data){
    console.log(data.success)
}
```

Read more about union types here:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types

Comment: I'm pretty sure that here you're just forcing `data` to be seen by the compiler as `UserInfo` (or more exactly as a type that has a `success` field). But if you would actually do the test, you'll see that `transformResponse` receives an object which wraps the actual UserInfo object. Read more about createApi mutations/transformResponse here: https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/mutations.

Comment: First of all, there was no transform response/createapi when I added the answer, it was only the interface and the async call. And i’m pretty sure that’s not forcing since it’s a checking before :). A forcing would be using something like : `(data as UserInfo).success`

Comment: Sorry. I meant "forcing" the TS compiler into seeing it as a type which holds that field. I wasn't talking about an actual cast. Bottom line is however that the data most likely is of type `{ data: UserInfo }`, as stated by the OP error.

Comment: Putting this check actually worked for me! Thanks

Answer (score 3):

try use loginUser(loginData).unwrap() in component

Answer (score 0):

The actual issue is found inside the `transformResponse` function, and how it 'tunnels' the response data further.

```
transformResponse: (rawResult : UserInfo) => {
  return rawResult
}
```

`rawResult` most likely is not of type `UserInfo`, but a `{ data: UserInfo }`. And that's exactly what you see in the error you get.

So to fix it, the function should look like this:

```
transformResponse: (rawResult: { data: UserInfo }) => {
  return rawResult.data
}
```

And then you code should work as expected, without any other `if`s.

```
let data = await loginUser(loginData);
console.log(data.success);
```

Comment: I guess the problem here is not in runtime, but typescript is complaining about the type mismatch. And I think it's a typings issue, the toolkit just cannot tell IDE that `transformResponse` could transform the type

Comment: Most likely not, because as I said above, rawResult is not of type `UserInfo`, but of type `{ data: UserInfo }`. So that's why we need to type the function parameter properly and then return `rawResponse.data`. By doing that, the statically type check should also get sorted out.